# Parameter passed by PHP via command line gets truncated

Tags: php, phantomjs

I am using PHP's `shell_exec()` to execute a program via a commandline, passing it an URL as the parameter.

**Problem:** The program seem to receive only a truncated version of the parameter. PHP passes the parameter

`http://www.mysite.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616&parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=200&sort=1`

but the program receives it as

```
http://www.mysite.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616
```

How can I prevent it from getting truncated after the `&`?

**PHP**

```
    $url = 'http://www.mysite.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616&parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=200&sort=1';
    $script = path('base')."application/phantomjs/httpget.js";
    $output = shell_exec("phantomjs $script $url");
```

**httpget.js**

```
// Get URL from command line parameter
var system = require('system');
var url = system.args[1];
console.log(url);
```

**Output**

`http://www.mysite.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616`

Comment: That code looks open to injection. What if someone has a URL `http://www.mysite.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616&parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=200&sort=1&foo=;rm -rf .`?

Comment: I can't see the problem...Is there anything more to this you aren't telling us about? On a side note... arxanas = very wise person

Comment: I did a `console.log(url)` within the `httpget.js` called by `phantomjs`, and it gave me the truncated version of the parameter. @arxanas Thanks! Didn't notice that. All URLs are defined by me, so it should be fine I guess

Comment: tried xdazz's answer and it works great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

```
$url = escapeshellarg($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote your string:

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616&parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=200&sort=1';
$script = path('base')."application/phantomjs/httpget.js";
$output = shell_exec("phantomjs $script \"$url\"");
```

For example, consider the following:

```
~ $ echo foo&bar
[1] 25361
foo
-bash: bar: command not found
[1]+  Done                    echo foo
~ $
```

vs

```
~ $ echo "foo&bar"
foo&bar
~ $
```

Comment: quoting is the way to go but please not manually - this **will** open a huge security hole if `$url` can contain untrusted data.

Comment: oh lawd now it's the answer when there's a better answer